# Java ImageIO.read() fails in browser

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I've made a game in Java, which naturally uses multiple images in it. I developed the game using Eclipse, and running it in Eclipse has no problems. At this point, the game is pretty much done, so I'm trying to put it on the internet, but I cannot get this game to run in a browser.

Loading it in a browser just shows a white screen, no error, just white. I know Java is up to date, I have run other java apps to test it and none of them have any problems. For a while I couldn't view the console because clicking on the blank app did nothing, but eventually I noticed that going to the notification in the taskbar allowed me to see the console. In there it lists the error as

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
```

and points me to the first image I load in my code. I have about 2 dozen images but it goes to the first one, upon commenting it out, the error redirects to the second, so I presume this is the same problem with every image. These images load fine in Eclipse, so I know the file paths are correct, somehow it doesn't show up in the browser.

The Java code which loads the first image:

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("images/debug/player.jpg"));
Constants.imgPlayer = new Picture(getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/debug/player.jpg"), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
```

This is being run when the program loads and is saving the image into this Picture class I created. All the Picture class does is hold the Image object as well as the width and height for later when I need to actually use the image. The only reason I have to use the `ImageIO.read()` is so I can get the width and height of each image.

For debugging I changed some of the code to this:

```
File testFile = new File("images/debug/player.jpg");
System.out.println("exists() = " + testFile.exists());
System.out.println("canRead() = " + testFile.canRead());

testFile.setReadable(true);
System.out.println("setReadable(true)");

System.out.println("canRead() = " + testFile.canRead());
image = ImageIO.read(testFile);
Constants.imgPlayer = new Picture(getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/debug/player.jpg"), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
```

In Eclipse, everything comes out as true, it exists, can be read, and then is read and works. In the browser (Chrome by the way), everything is false, it doesn't exist, cannot be read, and then throws an error when it tries to be read.

The HTML file is at [project]/bin/FinalProject.htm, though the main class is at [project]/bin/main/FinalProject.class. I'm wondering if because they are in separate folders, the file paths need to be different. I tried placing the HTML file in the same directory as the class, but then it would say it couldn't find the class though I'm certain I changed the file path to match.

I'm not really sure what to do at this point, Google searching hasn't really helped. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't use files -- use resources!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read a file from the local file system.  Java, running in a browser sandbox, does not allow that.  After all, you would not want someone else's game to be able to read your home banking records or similar.

Use image resources instead.

```
image = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"player.jpg");
```

See [getImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getImage%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29) in the Java docs.

Comment: Right, obviously it can't access EVERYTHING on the computer, that would be silly. But I would think it would be able to read files that are a part of the applet. How would I go about using resources to accomplish the same task?

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to reference an image that is located back on the server, including an appropriate link.

Comment: I do use the getImage() method to load the image itself, `getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/debug/player.jpg")` I only use the ImageIO.read() in order to get the width and height of the image. Is there a way to do that with resources?

Comment: I would assume this line: `File testFile = new File("images/debug/player.jpg");` is failing.  Is that the case?  What's the purpose of that line?  If that's not the line that's failing, which one exactly is?

Comment: @Doug: you can still use `ImageIO.read(...)`, but pass in a URL into this method via `getClass().getResource(resourceString)`, and use this as the parameter for the read method. The resourceString should be the path to your images relative to the location of the class files.

Comment: @Hovercraft How would I format the resourceString? The class this is running in is  `[project]/bin/main/FinalProject.class` while all the images are in `[project]/bin/images/someImage.ext`. I tried sticking "../" in front of the original path, but that didn't help. @Eric The error points to the `ImageIO.read(testFile)` line, and I'm reading it that way so I can get the width and height of the image later with `image.getWidth()` and `image.getHeight()`.

Comment: @Doug: could you perhaps move the images so that they are in a directory, say called "images" off of the /bin/main directory?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I moved the images as you suggested, (though it would be nice if I could keep the old structure), and running it in the browser no longer throws an error :), but it still doesn't work :(. I'm just getting a white box where the applet should be, though no errors are being thrown. Running it in Eclipse doesn't work either, it gives me a NumberFormatException and links me to a `Long.parseLong(String, int)` line which can't be displayed. I'm assuming that's part of Oracle's code, but it doesn't really tell me more than that.

Comment: I can't explain any of this without more information, and am puzzled by what you mean a problem with Oracle's code. The problem is with yours in all likelihood. I recommend that you try to simplify your problem greatly, that you create the most simple of JApplets that does nothing but show an image, and then try to solve the problem with this small class first before extending that solution to your present large program. This way you can post your entire code if you're still stuck.

Comment: I know the error is mine, but the error is linking me to a file that Eclipse won't display. I know for a fact that there is not a single Long used in my program. While I'm undoubtedly screwing up somewhere, I'm pretty sure it's not where Eclipse is sending me to.

Comment: @Doug: again, solve from simple, not from complex, at least to start with.